# Receiving the <Identifier> expected error and don't know why

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to call the void method addToList, which excepts two strings that will be passed to it via the user. I've checked the dataSource class to make sure it does in fact accept those as parameters. The problem is I keep receiving a identifier> expected error on that method call and i can't figure out why. I've called other methods using datasource and haven't had similar problems.

```
public class JListFromFile extends JFrame {

  private TextField wordA;
  private TextField wordB;
  private JButton openButton;
  private JButton newButton;
  private JButton addButton;
  private JButton deleteButton;
  private JButton saveButton;
  private TextField output;
  private JList listFromFile;
  private JPanel listPanel;
  private JPanel textPanel;
  private JPanel inputPanel;
  private JPanel buttonsPanel;
  private DataSource2 dataSource;
  private WordPair wordPair;
  public JListFromFile ()
  {
    // create the object to provide the data
    dataSource = new DataSource2();
    .
    .
    .
   private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
      listFromFile.setListData(new Object[0]);

      wordA.setEnabled(true);
      wordB.setEnabled(true);

      String inputStringA = wordA.getText();
      String inputStringB = wordB.getText();

      //here is the problem
      dataSource.addToList.(inputStringA, inputStringB);



    }
  }
```

Comment: There is a dot between `addToList` and the argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dot symbol is present after `addToList`

```
dataSource.addToList.(inputStringA, inputStringB);

                    ^_______ see the dot symbol.
```